# rails assets pipeline "Cannot allocate memory - nodejs"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

we've just upgraded to Rails 3.2.5 from Rails 3.0.7 and using the assets-pipeline compilation on the fly for the staging server, but some times we face this exception !

```
Showing /var/rails/appname/app/views/common/_my_partial.html.haml where line # raised:

Cannot allocate memory - nodejs /tmp/execjs20120613-17090-thoc8f.js 2>&1

Extracted source (around line #):

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
```

Although nothing fancy or huge memory allocations is done in the coffeescripts or in the images folder for example !

Thanks...

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, did you get to solve yours?? thanks!

Comment: @yorch: See my comment below. It fixed the problem in 30 seconds for me.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It's simple to spend the three minutes (maybe two if you type fast) to add a swap file to your server.

If you're running Ubuntu (not sure how well this works for other Linux flavors), just follow this tutorial from DigitalOcean:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

Voila!

Comment: I faced a similar problem when deploying with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, found this issue using SSH to connect to the instance and check the production logs, afterwards followed the tutorial and was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @MustafaELBanna Would you please mark this as the accepted answer? Many other people think it is.

Comment: @KyleCarlson can you put in a link to your blog post anyway?

Answer (score 13):

Based on the tutorial link provided by `Kyle Carlson`

---

Check swap space

`sudo swapon -s`

An empty list will confirm that you have no swap files enabled:

`Filename               Type        Size    Used    Priority`

Create and Enable the Swap File (swapfile)

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=256k`

Create a linux swap area:

`sudo mkswap /swapfile`

output:

```
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 262140 KiB no label, UUID=103c4545-5fc5-47f3-a8b3-dfbdb64fd7eb
```

Activate the swapfile:

`sudo swapon /swapfile`

check if you can see the swap summary.

```
swapon -s

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        262140  0   -1
```

Done!

---

**To make the swap file permenant**

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Paste in the following line:

`/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0`

Swappiness in the file should be set to 10. Skipping this step may cause both poor performance, whereas setting it to 10 will cause swap to act as an emergency buffer, preventing out-of-memory crashes.

```
echo 10 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
echo vm.swappiness = 10 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

set up the correct permissions on the swap file to not readable by the public:

```
sudo chown root:root /swapfile 
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
```

Answer (score 11):

Based on @tohi's answer, I created a script which you can paste into a terminal.

```
# Turn it (off) on
# sudo swapoff -a
sudo swapon -s

# Create a swap file
# 512k --> Swapfile of 512 MB
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k

# Use the swap file
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile

# make sure the swap is present after reboot:
sudo echo " /swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0 " >> /etc/fstab

# Set the swappiness (performance - aware)
echo 10 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
echo vm.swappiness = 10 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf           

# Change the permission to non-world-readable
sudo chown root:root /swapfile 
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
```

**Update**: If you need to resize the `/swapfile` at a later point check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/763717/508371

Answer (score 1):

We contacted the provider's support, and they are responded in 2 messages like this:

1. There are two things that can be causing this: Either **you are indeed running out of memory constantly** or **your Webby doesn’t have swap configured**.

We have a sysadmin checking it and we’ll respond to your ticket soon.

1. **Your swap was disable for some reason**, and that is why you were having memory issues. **I fixed the fstab entry**, and enable the swap on the right partition.
   You should be fine now.

And until now this error does not show :) Hope it will keep not showing for the future too ...

Thanks, and best of LUCK ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean
```

Restart your webserver / e.g.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Then:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```