# Capistrano -" Cannot allocate memory - git" while deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ubuntu, capistrano

I am deploying some new code with Capistrano and got this error message:

```
Cannot allocate memory - git
 ** [out :: IP] (
 ** [out :: IP] Errno::ENOMEM
 ** [out :: IP] )
 ** [out :: IP]
```

I've tried to remove old releases, but it didn't help. What caused this error and how can I get rid of it?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: which command have you issued?

Comment: `cap production deploy` (`cap production deploy:cold`)

Comment: please add output of `cat /proc/meminfo`

Comment: I had similar issues before on ubuntu. Have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34885004/784318 which tells you how to create a swap file which will save you some memory.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're running out of memory on your server. Check your free memory with any util(i prefer `top`). You might not be stopping your ruby processes after redeploy

Comment: Thanks @Avdept, I just realised another problem - I manually removed all releases from the folder `releases`, how could I fix it?

Comment: This is not releases related - this errors happens when you run out of ram on server

Answer (score -1):

It ended up that I needed to increase RAM memory on my server. I was using swap file before, by it didn't help me now.

I also tried to remove some files from the app that I didn't need anymore (CSV files having about 50-200MB), but it didn't help me too.