# Elastic beanstalk[Rails] deploy issue - Cannot allocate memory

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm experiencing the below error when deploying to Elastic beanstalk. This is a ruby app running Rails 4.1.9 and Ruby 2.1.4 on Puma.

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - node
(in /var/app/ondeck/app/assets/javascripts/my_javascript.js)
```

My javascript file is pretty basic, it looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/components/thirdpartylib.js

... and then basic functions
```

Unsure why exactly this is failing. I have not changed anything in the javascript file or the vendor assets.

Any ideas on how to resolve will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like the server has not enough memory to compile the assets. Could you maybe try to compile them locally?

Comment: Also, I think you can simply do `//= require components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min`

Comment: Thanks for the response @IsmaelAbreu . After further investigation, it seems my issue was related to just a very large amount of assets in my vendor/assets/components/*  that i actually didnt need. I have resolved the issue.

Comment: Oh. Cool! Don't forget to add that as an answer as it can help others in the future.

Comment: Was getting the same error and removing some of the assets didn't help. Adding swap did it for me as explained in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013755/rails-assets-pipeline-cannot-allocate-memory-nodejs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by removing a large amount of assets that were not needed or used, for instance i had the entire bootstrap project source and a few 3rd party library project source tree's and corresponding files, instead of just the src files that i was using.