# Deploying Rails to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hey guys I am trying to deploy my code to AWS using elastic beanstalk but keep running into errors during environment creation.

Initially I was getting an error stating that my ruby version was not 2.3.1 so I adjusted my ruby to 2.3.1 but now I get a whole host of errors.

here is the error log from the deployment. Is it an issue with my ruby version or is it something else just causing chaos?

Any help would be massively appreciated!

```html
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/passenger.log
-------------------------------------
[ 2017-03-22 13:31:02.5628 4511/7f352908f780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'webapp', 'cleanup_pidfiles' => 'L3RtcC9wYXNzZW5nZXItc3RhbmRhbG9uZS54N2pja2svdGVtcF9kaXJfdG91Y2hlci5waWQ=', 'default_group' => 'webapp', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'webapp', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/tmp/passenger-standalone.x7jckk/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.60', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'prestart_urls' => 'aHR0cDovLzAuMC4wLjA6ODAA', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'false', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.60', 'web_server_pid' => '4510', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '495', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '497' }
[ 2017-03-22 13:31:02.9945 4514/7f2bb74b7780 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4510/generation-0/request
[ 2017-03-22 13:31:03.2871 4522/7faa73974840 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4510/generation-0/logging
[ 2017-03-22 13:31:03.2875 4511/7f352908f780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2017/03/22 13:31:05 [error] 4530#0: *3 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
2017/03/22 13:31:05 [error] 4530#0: *3 testing "/var/app/current/public" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-nnwsbm.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-nnwsbm.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out
  Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
  Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
  Installing arel 7.1.4
  Installing execjs 2.7.0
  Installing awesome_print 1.7.0
  Installing aws-sigv4 1.0.0
  Installing jmespath 1.3.1
  Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ix2vs1.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ix2vs1.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/bcrypt-3.1.11/gem_make.out
  Installing sass 3.4.23
  Installing climate_control 0.1.0
  Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
  Installing method_source 0.8.2
  Installing thor 0.19.4
  Installing deep_merge 1.1.1
  Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
  Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/ext/unf_ext
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ub1f2j.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ub1f2j.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gem_make.out
  Installing rubyzip 1.2.1
  Installing table_print 1.5.6
  Installing hirb 0.7.3
  Installing multi_json 1.12.1
  Installing mimemagic 0.3.0
  Installing netrc 0.11.0
  Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/ext
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1bl1ee1.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1bl1ee1.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.20.0/gem_make.out
  Installing puma 3.4.0 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http11
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1o1w6ja.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1o1w6ja.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/puma-3.4.0/gem_make.out
  Using bundler 1.12.1
  Installing tilt 2.0.7
  Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
  Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
  Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1jbrlyp.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1jbrlyp.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.7.1/gem_make.out
  Installing rack-test 0.6.3
  Installing warden 1.2.7
  Installing sprockets 3.7.1
  An error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-03-22T13:32:18.892Z] INFO  [4678]  - [Application deployment railsapp-source@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_bundle_install.sh] : Activity failed.
[2017-03-22T13:32:18.892Z] INFO  [4678]  - [Application deployment railsapp-source@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2017-03-22T13:32:18.892Z] INFO  [4678]  - [Application deployment railsapp-source@1/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2017-03-22T13:32:18.893Z] INFO  [4678]  - [Application deployment railsapp-source@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup failed
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.810Z] INFO  [5422]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.811Z] INFO  [5422]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.811Z] INFO  [5422]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.811Z] INFO  [5422]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.811Z] INFO  [5422]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/access.log
-------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2017:13:31:05 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "-"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/ext/mri
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ix2vs1.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ix2vs1.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/bcrypt-3.1.11/gem_make.out
  Installing sass 3.4.23
  Installing climate_control 0.1.0
  Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
  Installing method_source 0.8.2
  Installing thor 0.19.4
  Installing deep_merge 1.1.1
  Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
  Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/ext/unf_ext
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ub1f2j.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1ub1f2j.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.2 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.7.2/gem_make.out
  Installing rubyzip 1.2.1
  Installing table_print 1.5.6
  Installing hirb 0.7.3
  Installing multi_json 1.12.1
  Installing mimemagic 0.3.0
  Installing netrc 0.11.0
  Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/ext
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1bl1ee1.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1bl1ee1.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.20.0 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/pg-0.20.0/gem_make.out
  Installing puma 3.4.0 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/ext/puma_http11
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1o1w6ja.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1o1w6ja.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.4.0 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/puma-3.4.0/gem_make.out
  Using bundler 1.12.1
  Installing tilt 2.0.7
  Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
  Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
  Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
  
  Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
  
      current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1jbrlyp.rb extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170322-4741-1jbrlyp.rb extconf.rb 2>&1
  
  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/nokogiri-1.7.1/gem_make.out
  Installing rack-test 0.6.3
  Installing warden 1.2.7
  Installing sprockets 3.7.1
  An error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
  Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-03-22T13:32:18.893Z] ERROR [4678]  : Command CMD-Startup failed!
[2017-03-22T13:32:18.894Z] INFO  [4678]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...nokogiri-1.7.1/gem_make.out\nInstalling rack-test 0.6.3\nInstalling warden 1.2.7\nInstalling sprockets 3.7.1\nAn error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.\nMake sure that `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling. \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":5,"events":[]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.795Z] DEBUG [5422]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.797Z] DEBUG [5422]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.800Z] DEBUG [5422]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-07665a49f1f6642b8)..
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.800Z] INFO  [5422]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-07665a49f1f6642b8)..
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.800Z] DEBUG [5422]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.800Z] INFO  [5422]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-03-22T13:35:14.800Z] INFO  [5422]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"
```

Comment: i think error is 'Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./'

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013755/rails-assets-pipeline-cannot-allocate-memory-nodejs

Comment: What size is your instance? I think @HardikUpadhyay has the right answer - your instance is too small.

Comment: I have updated my instance to 2gb and re-deployed, error seems to have changed slightly -- `  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler.rb:170:in `rescue in root': Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)`